# C# Methods, returns

Tags: c#

so basically I just started learning C# and yesterday I got the chance to learn about methods, I was a little bit confused about how are returns useful or what are they for, I know you can't have a return in a method that has void as part of the keyword and I know void means like "Don't do anything or  don't return anything" something like that.

Well knowing that void means that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Add(2,2);
        }

        static int Add(int numberOne, int numberTwo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numberOne + numberTwo);
            return numberOne + numberTwo;

        }
    }
}
```

How is the "return numberOne + numberTwo" useful in this code, I'm kinda stuck and I'm having a mental block why do I need the returns. **when I run this code I get something (4)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace MethodsTutorial
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm about to go into a method.");

            DoSomethingAwesome();

            Console.WriteLine("I'm back from the method.");
        }

        static void DoSomethingAwesome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm inside of a method, doing something awesome!");
        }
    }
}
```

And why in this code I also got something  ("I'm inside of a method, doing something awesome!" ) and I don't use the keyword **return** at the end, I don't know if I'm explaining myself well enough ( sorry if I don't English is not my first language) but I just need a basic and well explanation on how are returns useful and what are they for and when to use them and when to not use them.

Thank you...

Comment: IMO, I basically use methods with return types when I want to modify things inside my method's context only then just return the output, Void when i want to set something that is accessible elsewhere (global vars, etc)

Comment: @oneWhisper ... **Ed Hastings** ( http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180804/what-is-the-reason-behind-methods-with-return-values-and-methods-with-void ) will be helpful if you read.

Comment: maybe you can omit the `return` expression if you create another language if you are not newbie one day?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the method:

```
DoSomethingAwesome();
```

In your main `Program`, results in writing the sentence:

```
"I'm inside of a method, doing something awesome!"
```

because the `DoSomethingAwesome` method prints this value to the console, even if it does not return any value (it's a `void` method).

The method performs this action, regardless of the fact that it does not return a value, simply **because you called it**. If you wanted to use its value, as a returned string, it should look like this:

```
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm about to go into a method.");

            string result = DoSomethingAwesome();

            Console.WriteLine("I'm back from the method.");
        }

        static string DoSomethingAwesome()
        {
            return "I'm inside of a method, doing something awesome!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of a method declares what the caller should be expecting. When a method is declared with a `void` return type, it means that nothing gets returned from it, and therefore you don't need to use a `return` statement from `void` methods (because you aren't returning anything).

In the case below, you have:

```
static int Add(int numberOne, int numberTwo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numberOne + numberTwo);
    return numberOne + numberTwo;

}
```

This means that the method `Add` returns an integer to whoever is calling it.

From your main function, you call:

```
Add(2,2);
```

This means you're calling the function, but you aren't doing anything with the result (just throwing it away). Instead, do:

```
int result = Add(2, 2);
```

The integer returned (4 in this case) is stored in `result`, so you can do:

```
Console.WriteLine("The method returned {0}", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods need a return to get data *out* of them.
In the case of `int c = a + b`, you can think of this like your method `static int Add(int a, int b)`, which would be written as `int c = Add(a, b)`

In order to get the new value out of the method, the method needs to be able to return a value to the caller, which in this case then gets assigned to `c`.

The whole point of methods is to separate out frequently used portions of code, or to split large chunks of code into smaller, easier to understand chunks.

I'd suggest having a look at the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_4).

Answer (score 0):

The question here is quite basic and isnt only related to C#, infact almost every programming language uses `return` in methods.

Basically [`return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) indicates you wish to exit the method execution. Now when you have a `void` method, which is a method that does not return a value from the execution. Other than a void a method can return any type that is required.

Here is a basic example `void` method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Calculate(1 , 2);
    }

    static int c = 0;

    static void Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        c = a + b;
    }

}
```

Now in my `Calculate` method I am setting the value of my field `c` to the sum of `a + b`. This is basic, however the void method is not returning a value but modifying a value (`c`).

Now this could be written as:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        c = Calculate(1 , 2);
    }

    static int c = 0;

    static int Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

Where will notice my `Calculate` method is now returning an `int` which is the sum of `a + b`. This is being assigned to `c` from the calling method.

Now why use either case. Well in the first example the method `Calculate()` knew which variable should hold the result of the method. Therefore it set `c` to the sum.  In the second example the `Calculate` method simply returns the sum of `a + b`.

Now moving on to a more complex example. Lets say we build a calculator class whos responsibility is the manage the calculation.

```
class Calculator
{
    int sum = 0;

    public void Add(int a)
    {
        sum += a;
    }

    public void Subtract(int a)
    {
        sum -= a;
    }

    public int GetTotal()
    {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Which could be used as:

```
static void Main()
{
    var calculator = new Calculator();
    calculator.Add(5);
    calculator.Subtract(10);
    int total = calculator.GetTotal();
}
```

Again basic but now we have 3 methods. `Add`, `Subtract` and `GetTotal`. Both `Add` and `Subtract` are void methods as they are performing operations on the `sum` field. Where the `GetTotal` is `return`ing the sum.

Hope this helps a bit.